# Visual studio 2010 and Mysql server

Tags: c++, mysql

I am trying to connect VS2010 and mySQL server to write simple console application.
For 3 days i am trying to set everything up,but no luck.
I have some skills in c++ OOP,but never done anything like this.

So can someone point mi to tutorial or help here ,how to install and prepare all this thing before i could write any code.

i am using:
mysql server 5.6 and 
mysql connector c++

Main problem is mysql connector/c++ i followed documentation on their site but it is too hard for me.(what are boosts,Cmake).

Comment: Are you having problems compiling, linking, coding...?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need .NET connector.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/7bd1889e-f169-4c14-9a55-7043a5dd8881

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/65fc13/working-with-mysql-to-visual-studio-2010/